# Cannot connect to Server 2012 on port 8080

Tags: windows-server-2012

I admin a new server running MS Windows Server 2012 Essentials. The company uses a real-estate application called SoftPro. The SP installers cannot make their app work on the 2012 Essentials server I admin. After many hours of installing/tweaking the app, which uses SQL, it will run on the server, but no client PCs can run the app. They say it's because port 8080 is inaccessible on our server, and it does appear so. I've created rules in the Windows FW, and for testing purposes the FW was turned off. Still, 8080 is inaccessible. With svcs running using 8080 I cannot telnet to the port, netstat shows it listening, with asterisks. What are we missing?

Comment: You are debugging a problem which can lay on the network between your clients and server. First of all, localize on which machine your problem is - described behavior can be made by some firewall on the network or local/remote machine, misconfigured ip the server app listens on (like localhost only) and so on.

Comment: It could be an additional firewall; as part of an AV package, or e.g. the Nvidia controller firewall.

Comment: thank you for your replies. In fact, 8080 is inaccessible from any PC. Port 8080 is even inaccessible to the server itself. If I do a telnet to the server on port 8080 it fails, from clients and from the server itself. I think an early failed install has caused corruption and 8080 is still bound to remnants. We changed the SQL port from 8080 to another port, and the connection succeeds, but the app still won't work. It's looking like a bug in the app.